# Display four lists horizontally

Tags: css, html

How do I display four (4) unordered lists horizontally?

**lists.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
    <title>
        HTML Lists
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>
    HTML Lists
</h1>

<div id="container">
    <ul id="k">
        <li>katakana</li>
        <li>katakana</li>
        <li>katakana</li>
        <li>katakana</li>
        <li>katakana</li>   
    </ul>

    <ul id="ki">
        <li>katakana-iroha</li>
        <li>katakana-iroha</li>
        <li>katakana-iroha</li>
        <li>katakana-iroha</li>
        <li>katakana-iroha</li> 
    </ul>

    <ul id="h">
        <li>hiragana</li>
        <li>hiragana</li>
        <li>hiragana</li>
        <li>hiragana</li>
        <li>hiragana</li>   
    </ul>

    <ul id="hi>
        <li>hiragana-iroha</li>
        <li>hiragana-iroha</li>
        <li>hiragana-iroha</li>
        <li>hiragana-iroha</li>
        <li>hiragana-iroha</li> 
    </ul>

    <ul id="i">
        <li>Image</li>
        <li>Image</li>
        <li>Image</li>
        <li>Image</li>
        <li>Image</li>  
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
#container  {
    display: inline;
}

ul {
    list-style-position: inside;    
}

#k  {
    list-style-type: katakana;  
}

#ki{
    list-style-type: katakana-iroha;

}

#h {
    list-style-type: hiragana;
}

#hi {
    list-style-type: hiragana-iroha;
}

#i {
    list-style-image: url(images/myimage.png);
}
```

Comment: If you're using HTML5, try the columns.

Comment: You could also: `#container ul {
    float: left;    
}` and then clear after last `ul`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;    
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

and `display:block` on the `#i`

```
#i {
    list-style-image: url(images/myimage.png);
    display:block;
}
```

fiddle- <s>http://jsfiddle.net/nNRDa/</s> http://jsfiddle.net/nNRDa/1/

note: IE7 only supports `display:inline-block` on elements that are naturally inline.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work if with has been given to ul and container

```
#container  {
display: block;
width:100%;       
overflow:hidden;        
}

ul {
width:15%;
float:left;
margin:20px 3% 0 0;
display:block;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

width can also be given in px.